Adding PropertyGroup to selected object, but not all bpy.types.Object occurrences
I'm a beginner in learning Blender Python.
I want to write a script that creates and registers a property group, and then adds this property group to the selected object.
Up to this point, I only know how to add properties to all objects...
I currently haven't found any articles related to this issue, so I don't know if this is possible.
My script is like this; it’s not the full version, but it’s related to the issue I’m facing.
import bpy 


class propertyGP01(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    property01 : bpy.props.FloatProperty(name = "01", default = 1.0)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(propertyGP01)

def create_property():
    bpy.types.Object.my_propertygroup = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=propertyGP01)



if __name__ == '__main__':
register()

create_property()

Btw,I found another question when I test this script.
If I run script and only execute register() at the first time
then run script one more time and only execute create_property(),
And then the system will throw an error
ValueError: bpy_struct "Object" registration error: 'my_propertygroup' PointerProperty could not register (see previous error)

If both functions are executed together, no error will occur.
Can someone explain the difference between these two situations?
Thank you!

Please use the python tag when asking questions about python.

Hello, AFAIK it is not possible to add a Property Group to a single entity, it must be assigned to all occurrences of an ID type.

Oh well, looks like there's no other way... cheers for your help.
